# django records greater than particular date

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class sales_line(models.Model):
     sales_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     qty =   models.IntegerField()
     expected_end_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.sales_id
```

expected end date may be 'march 20,  2014' , 'april 29 2014' and so on,
how do i get all the records whose expected end date has crossed the current date

i have tried this :

```
current_date = time.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")

sales_line.objects.filter(expected_end_date__gt = current_date)
```

and

```
sales_line.objects.filter(expected_end_date__lt = current_date)
```

I am getting wrong data. where am i wrong???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should the format be `"%Y-%d-%m"` or something like `"%Y-%m-%d"`? Since `expected_end_date` is a date field, I would use `date` module:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
# or some other date:
today = date(2013, 3, 15)
sales_line.objects.filter(expected_end_date__lt=today)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `current_date` is a string, while `expected_end_date` is a DateField. DateField cannot be compared to strings, but can be compared to python `date` Objects.

Try this:

```
from datetime import date
current_date = date.today()

sales_line.objects.filter(expected_end_date__gt = current_date)
```